# Convert JSON array and nested data to CSV

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv

I have an array of JSON objects that I'm trying to convert to CSV where the end format would look something like this in excel:

| url | id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| http://www.example.com | F22 | a11y-true |
|  | C30 | a11y-unknown |
|  | RC30 | a11y-true |
| http://www.example.com/something-else | F22 | a11y-true |
|  | F23 | a11y-true |
|  | U10 | a11y-unknown |
|  | CR14 | a11y-unknown |
|  | RH03 | a11y-true |

given data such as...

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://www.example.com/something",
    "ids": [
      { "id": "F22", "type": "a11y-true" },
      { "id": "C30", "type": "a11y-unknown" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.example.com/something-else",
    "ids": [
      { "id": "F23", "type": "a11y-true" },
      { "id": "U10", "type": "a11y-unknown" },
      { "id": "CR14", "type": "a11y-unknown" },
      { "id": "RH03", "type": "a11y-true" }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried converting the JSON using:

```
const items = data
const header = Object.keys(items[0])
const csv = [header.join(','),...items.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName])).join(','))].join('\r\n')
console.log(csv)
```

but I end up with only the first level converted over:

```
"https://www.example.com/something",[{"id":"F22","type":"a11y-true"},{"id":"C30","type":"a11y-unknown"}]
"https://www.example.com/something-else",[{"id":"F23","type":"a11y-true"},{"id":"U10","type":"a11y-unknown"},{"id":"CR14","type":"a11y-unknown"},{"id":"RH03","type":"a11y-true"}]
```

How can I also get the nested arrays converted to CSV so that each `{}` is a single entry?

Comment: each row should be 'URL, id, type' your table shows  some as 'URL, id, type' and some as ' "", id, type' how is the NULL ("") value being assigned?  What will happen in Excel when you sort your data?

Comment: @BlindSpots - yes, each row should be URL | id | type. I'd pulled the `replacer` variable from an example, but I believe it can be removed. It should essentially be able to loop over the ids array of each object and grab the objects as individual id/type rows.

Comment: @Matt your data structure will be always like this(URL,ids)?

Comment: @Asraf - yes, it will always be an array of objects like the example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries for working with csv in js but you could just define header fields and then pick those field values when you loop over `ids`

```js
const data = [{"url":"https://www.example.com/something","ids":[{"id":"F22","type":"a11y-true"},{"id":"C30","type":"a11y-unknown"}]},{"url":"https://www.example.com/something-else","ids":[{"id":"F23","type":"a11y-true"},{"id":"U10","type":"a11y-unknown"},{"id":"CR14","type":"a11y-unknown"},{"id":"RH03","type":"a11y-true"}]}]

const separator = ', '
const header = ["url", "id", 'type']
const body = data.reduce((r, { url, ids }) => {
  ids.forEach((e, i) => {
    const first = i === 0 ? url : ''
    const other = header.slice(1).map(k => e[k]).join(separator)
    r.push([first, other].join(separator))
  })
  return r
}, [])

const result = `${header.join(separator)}\n${body.join('\n')}`

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is close, but it should only be a listing of the URL per object once, so that it's url in the first column, then all the objects of id/type to the right.

Comment: Why would you have url only in first row for that object and not in other rows also?

Comment: Since each URL has multiple id's/types, you don't need to print the same URL multiple times.

Comment: So you want to have url column, and only write url for the first row of that object and leave other rows empty for url column?

Comment: yes, the URL for each should only be written out once. Then the next URL is written and the associated id/types for it are listed to the right.

Comment: I've updated the table in my question to present how the data should look in the end.